# Prophecies refering or relating to one occassion or more?

Tags: commentaries, prophecies

Do prophecies only find their fulfillment once, or is it possible for them to be fulfilled more than once?
Do they only relate to one moment or one situation or is it also possible that they relate to several things?
Some things take place repeatedly in history or, in addition to the historical context, sometimes also seem to relate to later times.

Comment: Some prophecies seem to indicate one time events; some, such as the blessings and curses of Leviticus and Deuteronomy, seem to indicate consequences for actions that can happen many times